# eval "$(cat config_file | ./print_to_env_variables.py)" not working from within a function

Tags: python, bash

I have a simple bash script that is using a config.ini file that looks like this:

```
[a]
b=1
c=2
...
```

In the bash script, I sometimes do `eval "$(cat config_file | ./print_to_env_variables.py)"` where the python script is this:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.readfp(sys.stdin)
for sction in config.sections():
    print('declare -A {}'.format(sction))
    for k, v in config.items(sction):
        print("{}[{}]={}'.format(sction, k ,v))
```

Now, what this script does, is to add all sections into env variables, allowing me to use them from bash like this: `echo "${a[b]}"`

This only works if I do it like:

1. eval...
2. check the variable

but if I:

1. call a function that does the eval (less code dup)
2. check...

The variable does not exist.

Why is that?

Comment: For what it's worth, that's really a [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare` in a shell function declares a local variable that doesn't exist outside the function. To declare a global variable, you must add the `-g` switch.
See `help declare` or `man bash`.